# Using Android Intents from an asp.net webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net, android-intent

Okay, probably an extremely easy one but here goes.

I've got an asp.net webpage which operatives view on their Android handsets. They're running Chrome, though I don't know which version (but it should work fine).

I'm very new to Intents and they sound just like what I'm looking for, so here are two quick questions:

1 - how do I actually use an Intent in an asp.net webpage? How would I call one? Most stuff I've found so far sounds like it should be a proper Android project and is wanting things put in the manifest and so on. How would I do this in an asp.net webpage (with, of course, the option of Javascript and C#)?

2 - can I use the Intent to open the user's Google Drive and return the link to a file that they select?

Thanks.

EDIT - a bit of code, this is from a Javascript function that gets called. Previously this used to launch a file browser, however we don't want to upload a file:

```
function openfileDialog(obj)
{
    var tr = getParentRow(obj);
    var datalist = document.getElementById('<%=DataList1.ClientID%>');
    var Id = datalist.rows[tr.rowIndex].cells[0].childNodes[5].innerHTML;
    //document.getElementById("FileLoader").click();
    //<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
    //window.location, window.location.assign, window.location.href

    document.getElementById("txtFindMe").value = Id;
}
```

Basically, ignoring most of the code as it's unnecessary to the question, I assume I can call an intent using one of the three window.location calls. However, I still need to know a Google Drive intent, and also if there's one which would allow me to simply browse for a file and return its address, as well as put that address into another object somewhere on the page for other elements to use.

Comment: What you'll want to do is have a link on the webpage that uses a custom scheme like `myandroidapp://somedatahere` and then make the android application that uses that scheme to launch an activity. If you wanted to launch google drive you would have to use their scheme

Comment: to open an intent : https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: Zaki - was actually having a look at that page when you replied.